# Unable to remove table rows to replace with new one

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Bootstrap in one of my Java project based on PLAY framework. On one of my clicks I am populating data in a table by fetching the div for each row of the table (based on how many row's data is send by server). I am fetching the whole div html by $.get() and then by using .last() method I am populating data in various columns of fetched table. So this makes my table a runtime-loaded-element rather than static element.

While clicking the button first time, everything is fine. But I am failing to remove the existing rows and replace them with new rows on subsquent clicks, instead the new data is binded below the existing data.

I have tried to remove existing rows before fetching new rows by using .remove(), .empty(), .removeData() on the divs that were fetched previously. I even tried to use .each() on all the existing divs to remove them but somehow nothing of this works for me.

What I have concluded is either of the below:

1. The removal methods are working both on old and newly fetched divs (as they both obviously have common class).
2. These removal methods do not work on runtime-loaded-elements (delegate as we say).

It has been a while now fiddling with this issue and getting nowhere. Can someone point me to a better direction of achieving the same.

My basic jQuery function used for the above is as follows. I have tried using various methods on the same, however now it shows the latest method I had used:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchButton').click(function(){
        $('body').find('.jresultList').empty();
        $("#jErrDisplayy").css("display","none");
        var input,div,range;
        input= $("#inputField").val();
        $.ajax({
                url: "/fetchPTIDatas",
                data: {num:$('#inputField').val()}, //{id:$('#conBid').val()},
                timeout: 10000,
                type: "POST",
                cache: false,
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend:function(jqXHR, options) {
                    if(input.length<7||input.length>11){
                        alert("Please enter a valid input");    
                        jqxhr.abort();
                    } 

                }
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert("ajax call failed");
            }).done(function(resp, textStatus, jqXHR){
                if(resp.errorcode){
                    $("#jErrDisplayy").css("display", "block");
                    $('.jerrorr').html("We couldn't not look up the entered code. Please enter a valid code");
                }else{
                    range= resp.PageContainerList.length;
                    alert(range);
                    $.get("/fetchresultList", function(data){
                        $('body').find('.tableHeader').css('display', 'block');
                        $('jresultList').each(function(){
                            $('jresultList').remove();
                        });
                        for (var i=0; i <=range; i++) {
                            $('body').find('.jContrList').append(data);
                            div = $('body').find('.jContrList .jresultsList').last();
                            div.find('.accordion-body').attr('id', "collapse" + i);
                            div.find('.accordion-toggle').attr('href', "#collapse" + i);
                            div.find('.jContNo').html(resp.PageContainerList[i].container);

                            }

                    });
                                        }
                        });
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Add your code here..

Comment: tl;dr - where is your code

Comment: where is you html code !!. $('jresultList').remove(); will select all tags named ***jresultList***, may you have to add your html code, but if ***jresultList*** is a class name your code should be like $('.jresultList').remove();

Comment: I am extremely sorry for this...but yes this is a class and in my code believe me, I have used it as $('.jresultList'). But still the issue persists.